# Laravel Spatie unable to restrict UserController

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, user-roles, laravel-permission

Currently I have users.index blade which I would like to restrict. However, I failed to restrict it.

I have tried to create another test blade and a TestController and I have set permission to it and it works fine.

However with UserController, there is just no way to restrict Users from accessing it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use DB;

    class TestController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Restricting pages
         */
            public function __construct()
        {
            $this -> middleware('permission:test-list', ['only' => ['index']]);
        }
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            return view('test.index');
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

views/test/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content') 


<p>Testing Page</p>
@endsection
```

These are the results if I don't permit a particular user role to access this page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N00En.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI80Z.png)

So the above is the correct behavior. 
However when it comes to user.index , I applied the same technique in the constructor of the UserController but it doesn't work

app/Http/Controllers/UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use DB;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function construct() 
    {
        $this -> middleware('permission:user-list', ['only' => ['index']]);

    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC') -> paginate(5);
        return view('users.index' , compact('data')) -> with('i' , ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::pluck('name','name') -> all();
        return view('users.create',compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);
        $input = $request -> all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        $user = User::create($input);
        $user -> assignRole($request -> input('roles'));
        return redirect() -> route('users.index') -> with('success','User created successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('users.show',compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $roles = Role::pluck('name','name') -> all();
        $userRole = $user->roles -> pluck('name','name') -> all();
        return view('users.edit',compact('user','roles','userRole'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this -> validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);
        $input = $request->all();
        if( ! empty($input['password'])) { 
            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        } else {
            $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
        }
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user -> update($input);
        DB::table('model_has_roles') -> where('model_id',$id) -> delete();
        $user -> assignRole($request -> input('roles'));
        return redirect() -> route('users.index') -> with('success','User updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        User::find($id) -> delete();
        return redirect() -> route('users.index')  -> with('success','User deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Result [I am still able to view this Blade in front end despite not having the permission to view this page]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nILvG.png)

This is my role-has-permission table[role-has-permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ySzh.png)

This is my role table 
[role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbRB0.png)

This is my permission table
[permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNzQ6.png)

This is my model-has-roles table [model-has-roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMr2N.png)

This is my model-has-permissions table [model-has-permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiXWy.png)

Comment: Could you please show the "role_has_permissions" table?

Comment: @sachinkumar this is my roles_has_permissions table

Comment: Where? I can't able to see that.

Comment: @sachinkumar sorry just updated it. Please try again

Comment: can you try by clearing the cache, routing cache, view? and also try composer dump-autoload.

Comment: @sachinkumar I have tried php artisan config:clear ,  php artisan cache:clear and composer dump-autoload. Issue still persist.

Comment: Ok. let me show the "model_has_permissions" and "model_has_roles" tables

Comment: @sachinkumar  Noted, have already updated my "model_has_permissions" and "model_has_roles" tables .  Please take a look . Thank you very much

Comment: Let us show the output of this snippet "$permissions = $user->getAllPermissions();"

Comment: I have tried this method inside a userController@show

 public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $permissions = $user->getAllPermissions();
        return $permissions;
        
    }

This is what I got back 

https://prnt.sc/pe9wsu

Comment: @sachinkumar I found the solution based on what the user below recommended . What I did was 


Route::middleware(['auth', 'permission:user-list']) -> group(function (){
    Route::resource('users' , 'UserController');
});

Comment: That's good. But the thing that makes me surprise why the functionality is not working in the constructor.

Comment: @sachinkumar Exactly I Don't understand as well, it miraculously worked in the web.php , Router .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict specific routes or all you can do something like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'permission:user-list'])->group(function (){

Route::get('/create', 'WelcomeController@create')->name('welcome');
 ...
 ...
 ..

});
```

or you can replace

```
public function construct() 
{
    $this -> middleware('permission:user-list', ['only' => ['index']]);

}
```

to

```
public function construct() 
{
    $this -> middleware('permission:user-list')->except(['index']);

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @EyadJaabo , I tried using this way and it suddenly works 

Route::middleware(['auth', 'permission:user-list'])->group(function (){
    Route::resource('users' , 'UserController');
});

Thank you very much